# When using a drop down list in google sheets, how do I pull in a figure from a different sheet based on the drop down item selected?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am making a price list for products where I have 2 separate sheets.
The first sheet is the varies prices from suppliers, my business mark up and VAT. Also in the first is a section for product addons, for each I have created a dropdown list the pulls the items from a range in the second sheet.

Drop Down List
[image]

Inside the field column I want to be able to select an item from each list and pulls in the price from the second sheet.

Price Addons
[image]

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately the combination of your description and images does not give enough info to produce a credible solution. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos Thanks for your reply. Please see my shared link for my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w5uEzCu5898KSVrX7M-8XQo416ZMSDU8Ya4xMf-CmcI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am trying to make a formula that will allow me to select an item from the addons drop down list, this will lookup the item in the Add on sheet and pull the figure in to the cell alongside the drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
=INDEX(iferror(VLOOKUP(J9:J23, 
           QUERY({'Add ons'!A3:B;'Add ons'!D3:E;'Add ons'!G3:H;'Add ons'!J3:K}, 
                   "where Col1 is not null"),2,0)))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Comment: I have noticed an issue. I am having conflicts for three of the drop down items where they have 'Yes' and 'No' options. All other dropdowns have unique select options apart from 3 drops downs. These 3 drops downs pull in the same figure from the 'Add on' sheet. Any ideas or clues to what it could be? 

Result - 

Spy Viewer = Yes = £6.00
Secure By Design = Yes = £6.00 

Expected - 
Spy Viewer = Yes = £6.00
Secure By Design = Yes = £57.50